# MySQL/nodejs: query results being artificially limited

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've got a long-running MySQL db operation on my node.js server. This operation performs an `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT ... FROM` statement that should result in a table with 1000's of rows, but I only end up with a fraction of that amount. I'm noticing that my node server shows the request *always* taking exactly 120000 MS, so it's led me to believe that something -- either MySQL or node's MySQL connector -- is artificially limiting my results from the SELECT statement.

Some things to note:

- I've tried adding my own `LIMIT 0,100000` and my final result is exactly the same as if I had no LIMIT clause at all.
- If I run with no WHERE clause, my resulting data goes through July of 2013. I can force later data by adding a WHERE theDateField > '2013-08-01'; I can conclude from this that the query itself should be working, but that something is limiting it.
- I get the same result by running my query in MySQL workbench after removing the LIMIT via preferences (this suggests that the MySql server itself may be the problem)

Is anyone aware of a setting or something that could cause this behavior?

Comment: Anything in the MySQL log files?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you have a non-standard [`sql_select_limit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_select_limit). The default would be huge (_"2^32)–1 or (2^64)–1"_).